# Set raws from a table in the database into radio buttons

Tags: android, database, radio-button

As for [this tutorial](http://mobileyogi.in/mobile-programming/populating-radio-buttons-in-android-with-database-data/) i am trying to set this cursor and got it set perfectly.
But as I understood, it gets the value from array of string from the table.

I have table with first column is id and the second column is name.
The thing is that I want the cursor get each name (every name has it's own raw), and the code above is looking for the columns and not for the raw.
The current results are the first name only.

The db is:

```
public class DatBas {

    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_SHOURS = "start_hour";
    public static final String KEY_SMINUTE = "start_minute";
    public static final String KEY_SDATE = "start_date";
    public static final String KEY_AMOUNT = "amount";
    public static final String KEY_SIDE = "side";
    public static final String KEY_KIND = "kind";

    public static final String KEY_ROW_b_ID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_b_IMAGE_PATH = "uri_b";
    public static final String KEY_b_NAME = "b_name";
    public static final String KEY_b_GENDER = "b_gender";
    public static final String KEY_b_BORN_DATE_YEAR = "b_age_year";
    public static final String KEY_b_BORN_DATE_MONTH = "b_age_month";
    public static final String KEY_b_BORN_DATE_DAY = "b_age_day";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "TamatDB";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "stop_watch_records";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE_SETTINGS = "settings";

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3 ;

    private TamarDatabase thdb;
    private static Context tcontext;
    private SQLiteDatabase tdb;

    private static class TamarDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public TamarDatabase(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            String ctData = "CREATE TABLE  " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ( "
                    + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                    + KEY_SHOURS + " TEXT, " + KEY_SMINUTE
                    + " TEXT, " + KEY_SDATE + " TEXT, "
                    + KEY_AMOUNT + " TEXT, " + KEY_SIDE
                    + " TEXT, " + KEY_KIND + " TEXT );";
            db.execSQL(ctData);

            String ctSettings = "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE_SETTINGS
                    + " ( " + KEY_ROW_b_ID
                    + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                    + KEY_b_IMAGE_PATH + " TEXT, " + KEY_b_NAME
                    + " TEXT, " + KEY_b_GENDER + " TEXT, "
                    + KEY_b_BORN_DATE_YEAR + " TEXT, "
                    + KEY_b_BORN_DATE_MONTH + " TEXT, "
                    + KEY_b_BORN_DATE_DAY + " TEXT);";
            db.execSQL(ctSettings);

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE_SETTINGS);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    public DatBas(Context c) {
        tcontext = c;
    }

    public DatBas open() throws SQLiteException {
        thdb = new TamarDatabase(tcontext);
        tdb = thdb.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase getReadableDatabase() throws SQLiteException {
        thdb = new TamarDatabase(tcontext);
        tdb = thdb.getReadableDatabase();
        return tdb;
    }


    public void close() {
        tdb.close();
    }

    public long createEntry(String sh, String sm, String sd, String at,
            String tside, String tkind) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_SHOURS, sh);
        cv.put(KEY_SMINUTE, sm);
        cv.put(KEY_SDATE, sd);
        cv.put(KEY_AMOUNT, at);
        cv.put(KEY_SIDE, tside);
        cv.put(KEY_SIDE, tkind);

        return tdb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
    }

    public long createEntrySettings(String pt, String bn, String bg,
            String bbdy, String bbdm, String bbdd) {
        ContentValues cv2 = new ContentValues();
        cv2.put(KEY_b_IMAGE_PATH, pt);
        cv2.put(KEY_b_NAME, bn);
        cv2.put(KEY_b_GENDER, bg);
        cv2.put(KEY_b_BORN_DATE_YEAR, bbdy);
        cv2.put(KEY_b_BORN_DATE_MONTH, bbdm);
        cv2.put(KEY_b_BORN_DATE_DAY, bbdd);

        return tdb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_SETTINGS, null, cv2);
    }

    public String getData() {
        String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_SHOURS, KEY_SMINUTE,
                KEY_SDATE, KEY_AMOUNT, KEY_SIDE, KEY_KIND };
        Cursor c = tdb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null,
                null);
        String results = "";

        int iRaw = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
        int iShours = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SHOURS);
        int iSminute = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SMINUTE);
        int iDate = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SDATE);
        int iAmount = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_AMOUNT);
        int iSide = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SIDE);
        int iKind = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_KIND);

        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
            results = results + "the id is " + c.getString(iRaw)
                    + " the sart hour is " + " " + c.getString(iShours)
                    + " the start minute is " + " " + c.getString(iSminute)
                    + " the start date is " + " " + c.getString(iDate)
                    + " the amount is " + " " + c.getString(iAmount)
                    + " the side is " + " " + c.getString(iSide)
                    + " the kind is " + " " + c.getString(iKind) + "\n";
        }
        return results;
    }

    public String getDataSettings() {
        String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROW_b_ID, KEY_b_IMAGE_PATH,
                KEY_b_NAME, KEY_b_GENDER, KEY_b_BORN_DATE_YEAR,
                KEY_b_BORN_DATE_MONTH, KEY_b_BORN_DATE_DAY };
        Cursor c = tdb.query(DATABASE_TABLE_SETTINGS, columns, null, null,
                null, null, null);
        String results = "";

        int iRawbId = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROW_b_ID);
        int iBIPath = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_b_IMAGE_PATH);
        int iBName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_b_NAME);
        int iGender = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_b_GENDER);
        int iBBDateYear = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_b_BORN_DATE_YEAR);
        int iBBDateMonth = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_b_BORN_DATE_MONTH);
        int iBBDateDay = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_b_BORN_DATE_DAY);

        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
            results = results + " id " + " " + c.getString(iRawbId)
                    + " path " + " " + c.getString(iBIPath)
                    + " name " + " " + c.getString(iBName)
                    + " gender " + " " + c.getString(iGender)
                    + " year " + " " + c.getString(iBBDateYear)
                    + " month " + " " + c.getString(iBBDateMonth)
                    + " day " + " " + c.getString(iBBDateDay) + "\n";
        }
        return results;
    }

    public String getDataSettingsbName() {
        String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROW_b_ID, KEY_b_NAME };
        Cursor c = tdb.query(DATABASE_TABLE_SETTINGS, columns, null, null,
                null, null, null);
        String results = "";

        int iRawbId = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROW_b_ID);
        int iBName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_b_NAME);

        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
            results = c.getString(iRawbId)+ c.getString(iBName)+ "\n";
        }
        return results;
    }

    public DatBas delete() {
        tdb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, null, null);
        tdb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE_SETTINGS, null, null);
        return null;
    }

    public static class TamarDatabaseCursor extends SQLiteCursor {

        /** The query for this cursor */
        private static final String QUERY = "SELECT _id, b_name FROM settings";

        /** Cursor constructor */
        private TamarDatabaseCursor(SQLiteDatabase db,
                SQLiteCursorDriver driver, String editTable, SQLiteQuery query) {
            super(db, driver, editTable, query);
        }

        /** Private factory class necessary for rawQueryWithFactory() call */

        private static class Factory implements SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory {
            public Cursor newCursor(SQLiteDatabase db,
                    SQLiteCursorDriver driver, String editTable,
                    SQLiteQuery query) {
                return new TamarDatabaseCursor(db, driver, editTable, query);
            }
        }

        /* Accessor functions get one per database column */

        public int getActressId() {
            return getInt(getColumnIndexOrThrow("settings._id"));
        }

    }

    public TamarDatabaseCursor getActress() {
        SQLiteDatabase d = getReadableDatabase();
        TamarDatabaseCursor c = (TamarDatabaseCursor) d.rawQueryWithFactory(
                new TamarDatabaseCursor.Factory(), TamarDatabaseCursor.QUERY,
                null, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        return c;
    }




}
```

the activity is:

```
DatBas db = new DatBas(Tamar_appActivity.this);
    TamarDatabaseCursor c = db.getActress();

    if (c.moveToFirst())
        DisplayRadioButton(c);

    else
        Toast.makeText(this, "No title found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    db.close();

}

public void DisplayRadioButton(Cursor c) {
    for (int i = 1; i < (c.getColumnCount()); i++) {
        RadioGroup radiogroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.bNameSelectGroup);
        RadioButton rdbtn = new RadioButton(this);
        rdbtn.setId(i);
        rdbtn.setText(c.getString(i));
        radiogroup.addView(rdbtn);      
    }

}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "raws"? I understand that you have two columns, and you want too get each name, you only have two columns, a id and a name columns, so by each name talking about the column names? :S

Answer (score 0):

You don't understand how cursors and querys work.

You query the database and tell it to return the information from certain columns in the database that match certain conditions.  The database sends you the data in a cursor which contains the information from all the columns that you specified from all the rows that matched your request, in the order you specified.

```
SELECT _id, firstname, lastname FROM actresses
```

The above will return the the data from the _id, firstname lastname columns from of every row in the database.

So if you had three actresses in there it would return three records, the information being from the three columns you specified.

```
SELECT _id, firstname FROM actresses
```

This one would return only information in the _id and firstname columns of each record.

**EDIT**

You only get the name because that is all you asked for when you made the query:

```
private static final String QUERY = "SELECT _id, b_name FROM settings
```

Change that to return more columns and you will get more radio buttons.

Comment: Ok, So what is the resone of the results has just the first raw in that table?

Comment: It sounds like yur query isn't correct.  Edit your question and post your code so we can take a look (your code, not the tutorial).

Comment: I want to return just the name. the problem is that it returns just the first raw and not all the raws in the table (so i cannot get name number 2  and so on...)

Comment: Do you have more than one name in the database??  If you do I think I would look at your custom cursor... I'd try it with a standard cursor and see what happens.

Comment: But that is not the point of this tutorial? To pull out of a database the names from a table an represent theme within radio buttons?

Comment: What cursor you use has no bearing (that I can see from your code) on  how they get displayed.  The cursor is diofferent from  that adapter.

Comment: So what should be the way to set radio button out from the table column? (all his raws). As you can see in the code, I do have cursors but they are located in the database helper and they output string variable